# How to use branches with multiple projects and Teamcity

Tags: svn, branch, teamcity, branching-strategy

I'm looking for a best practice for the following situation:

I have one bll/dal project, and tree UI projects that uses the bll/dal project.
In the beginning we putted it all in one trunk folder on a SVN-repository. We are using userbranches, so each userbranch had all sourcecode.

Now we started using TeamCity as a buildserver, and we wanted that each project has it own product version. 
So we splitted up the trunk on different SVN repositories (each project on another SVN), so that every project has it own revisionnumber in its productversion.

We have an continuous integration and a continuous deployment for each project on teamcity.
4 project gives 8 configurations

Now we want also for each user a CI of his branch. But now we have to make for each project an user branches, so that will 4 user branches for each user.
This involves also that we need to configure 4 CI-configuration for each user on TeamCity...

Now I'm just wondering, is this a good approach, or are there better solutions...?

Thanks in advance.

Bruno

Comment: First you should forget about "revisionnumber" you should use tags instead. Furthermore you should think about a dependency solution, depending in which language you are developing (Java=> Maven, Gradle, Ivy) to solve your dependency problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for best practices, I believe it is never good to have individual branches for each user ( developer? ) and "CI" in this sense is not CI at all - it is more a personal build than anything else.

For branches in TeamCity, you can add branch specific build configuration within the Project. For example if there is a "build" build configuration, you can add "build-release" for the release branch etc.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this new feature in 6.5 EAP](http://teamcitydev.blogspot.com/2011/04/last-eap-build-before-65-parametrized.html) may help you (parametrized CVS roots).

Comment: I can confirm teamcity 6.5 does what requested (I'm currently using it)